# Dimension of a product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I took this question from Zhang, Fuzhen. Linear Algebra (Johns Hopkins Studies in the Mathematical Sciences):

> Let V and W be vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$. Denote by V × W the collection of all ordered pairs (v, w), where v $\in$ V and w $\in$ W, and define (v1, w1) + (v2, w2) = (v1 + v2, w1 + w2) and k(v, w) = (kv, kw), k $\in$ $\mathbb{F}$.

I am particularly stuck with part (c) and (f):

> (c) Find dim(V × W), given that dim(V) = m and dim(W) = n.
>
> (f) What is the dimension of $M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) × M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

where $M_{2}$ stands for two by two matrices. I think the answer to part (c) should be m+n and the answer to part (f) should be 8, but the answer key says  mn for (c) and 16 for (f). I appreciate any clarification.

Thank you,

Comment: Wouldn't it be the tensor products $V\otimes W$ and $M_2(\mathbf R)\otimes M_2(\mathbf R)$?

Comment: $\dim\mathbb{R}^2=2$. The book might have contained a typo.

Comment: Or you might have misread $\times$ for $\otimes$. :)

Comment: @Leaning I put all the symbols as they appeared on the kindle version of the textbook. But based on the definition given, shouldn't the symbol be $\times$ anyway?

Comment: There is another way to construct a new vector space from $2$ vector spaces, which is called the tensor product, and the symbol for it is $\otimes$. The result $mn$ and $16$ applies to this tensor product, which is the reason I gave my second comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the definition of "$\times$" you have given, one can prove that $$\{(v,0_W): v\in B_V\}\cup \{(0_V,w): w\in B_W\}$$ is a basis of $V\times W$ where $B_V$ is a basis of $V$ ans $B_W$ is a basis of $W$.
This implies that $\dim(V\times W)=m+n$.